# Angular 5 reload data for all sub components after update

Tags: angular, user-interface, redirect, angular5

I have a component **PersonTabsComponent** which extends an abstract component **PersonParentComponent**(contains the person model) where I use some info from the model. Inside this component I also have defined other components, for the address and other info that also extend the same **PersonParentComponent**.

What I wanna do is after updating the person model redirecting to the same route and see the changes in all the components.The data is injected in all components using a a resolver **PersonResolver** and **activatedRoute**.

```
export abstract class PersonParentComponent {

  person: Person= new ..();
  personRegister: Person= new ..();;

  protected constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                        private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      const persons = data['person'];
      this.person = persons[0];
      this.personRegister = persons[1];
    });
  }
...
}
```

To be able to redirect to the same route and force the resolver to call for the data I have defined the route like this ( **runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'**):

```
      {
    path: 'personen/:personId',
    component: PersonTabsComponent,
    resolve: {person: PersonVeResolver},
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  }

    @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Than after performing the update I redirect to the same route using:

```
this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
this.router.navigate(['personen/'.concat(String(id))]);
```

The problem I have is the the data is updated only in the **PersonTabsComponent** component not also in the sub components contained inside it, even if the resolve method for the resolver runs.

Do you know if I am missing something or how can I force the sub components to also reload the data?

PS: I don't wanna do the window.location.reload() nasty solution. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar behavior with my components, and the reason was the way I was loading the data in the children components.
If you load your data in one of the component's lifecycle hooks (for example ngOnInit) your children components won't reload its data when you navigate to the same route, because they are already loaded in your page.

After realizing that, I started to follow the "Data flow" approach that was described in this post: https://bulldogjob.com/articles/539-scalable-angular-application-architecture, where you have one top component that loads all the data needed, and that data is passed to the children components through @Inputs. Building my components that way, solved my issues.

As a work around, you can also create a new component to work as a redirector. So you create a new route that loads this new component, and in it you redirect the browser to the route you want. Doing that, yo will load every component (the main one, and its children) again, without doing window.location.reload(). 
The drawback of this approach is that it will mess with your navigation history (i.e. it will break the back button), and you will have to fix it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to implement the Redux [link](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-and-redux-ecd22ea53492) framework for state management.

it is a good one approach for managing the state of application. it is a single, immutable data store.
One-way data flow.
An approach to change based on pure functions and a stream of actions.